# What is a Pythonic way to add a negative multiplication as a keyword argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, idioms, keyword-argument

For some context, I am coding some geometric transformations into a python class, adding some matrix multiplication methods. There can be many 3D objects inside of a 3D "scene". In order to allow users to switch between applying transformations to the entire scene or to one object in the scene, I'm computing the geometric center of the object's bounding box (cuboid?) in order to allow that geometric center to function as the "origin" in the objects Euclidean space, and then to apply transformation matrix multiplications to that object alone.

My specific question occurs when mapping points from scene space to local object space, I subtract the geometric center from the points. Then after the transformation, to convert back, I add the geometric center to the points. Is there a pythonic way to change my function from adding to subtracting via keyword argument?

I don't like what I have now, it doesn't seem very pythonic.

```py
def apply_centroid_transform(point, centroid, reverse=False):
    reverse_mult = 1
    if reverse:
        reverse_mult = -1

    new_point = [
        point[0] - (reverse_mult * centroid["x"]),
        point[1] - (reverse_mult * centroid["y"]),
        point[2] - (reverse_mult * centroid["z"]),
    ]

    return new_point
```

I don't want to have the keyword argument be `multiply_factor=1` and then make the user know to type `-1` there, because that seems unintuitive.

I hope my question makes sense. Thanks for any guidance you may have.

Comment: Not much to do about it, I think, but you can write: `reverse_mult = -1 if reverse else 1`.

Comment: Without any expert knowledge in geometric transformation jargon, `inverse` seems more clear to me. That being said, there's a need for a pictographic explanation in the documentation of the method either way.

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```py
def apply_centroid_transform(point, centroid, reverse=False):
    return [point[i] - [1, -1][reverse]*centroid[j] for i, j in enumerate('xyz')]
```

It is not very readable, but it is very concise :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
def apply_centroid_transform(point, centroid, reverse=False):
    if reverse:
        centroid["x"]= centroid["x"]*-1
        centroid["y"]= centroid["y"]*-1
        centroid["z"]= centroid["z"]*-1

    new_point = [
        point[0] - (centroid["x"]),
        point[1] - (centroid["y"]),
        point[2] - (centroid["z"]),
    ]

    return new_point
```

assuming there are also other components in the dict centroid.
In general I would advice to create a dataclass "centroid" and a dataclass "point" with x,y,z as attributes to make the code more readable.

This would look like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Centroid(dataclass):
    x: float
    y: float
    z: float
    
    def reverse(self):
        return Centroid(x=self.x*-1, x=self.y*-1, x=self.z*-1)

@dataclass
class Point(dataclass):
    x: float
    y: float
    z: float

def apply_centroid_transform(point: Point, centroid: Centroid, reverse: Bool=False):
    if reverse:
        centroid = centroid.reverse()

    return Point(point.x - (centroid.x), point.y - (centroid.y), point.z - (centroid.z)))
```

Comment: Just be careful not to change the `centroid` variable, which is mutable, inside the function, as it will make that function have that as a side-effect.

Comment: @Dr. V well depending on what is required, but you are right, I will change the answer such that the transform function will return a new, transformed, Centroid object instead of changing the existing one. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a scalar to the transformation and it just so happens that -1 moves a local object back to scene space. So, make the function generic and add a doc string.

```
def apply_centroid_transform(point, centroid, scalar=1):
    """Move point from centroid with scale. By default, scalar=1 and
    moves from scene to local object space. With -1, the operation is
    reversed."""
    new_point = [
        point[0] - (scalar * centroid["x"]),
        point[1] - (scalar * centroid["y"]),
        point[2] - (scalar * centroid["z"]),
    ]

    return new_point
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you like, you can do this:

```
def apply_centroid_transform(point, centroid, reverse=False):
    op = float.__sub__ if reverse else float.__add__
    return [op(p_i, c_i) for p_i, c_i in zip(point, centroid)]
```

Comment: I think that's horribly weird and hard to read, not pythonic at all, but that may be subjective. Either way, it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: I admit it's not beautiful - and, if it doesn't answer the question at all, then I also admit I don't understand the question. My answer just shows some "alternative" elements in the python language that can be used.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it's obvious, but maybe it's actually me who doesn't understand the question, we'll see :)